# position absolute and overflow hidden overlapping content

Tags: overflow, css-position, absolute, overlap

[image]I have four divs in a row and then under this the footer, however the footer moves behind the images instead of directly underneath the div.

I think it is something to do with the positioning but can't work out how to stop the overlapping.

Any help would be appreciated,

Cheers

```
<div id="image-nav">
    <div id="image-nav1">
        education
    </div>
    <div id="image-nav2">
    repairs
    </div>
    <div id="image-nav3">
    finance
    </div>
    <div id="image-nav4">
    gold
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="footer-wrap">
        <div class="section group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                    links
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                    details
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                    newsletter
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


#image-nav{
    width:100%;
    background:#C03;
    position:relative;
    }
#image-nav1{
    background:#0FF;
    width:25%;
    position: absolute;
    }
#image-nav2{
    background:#069;
    width:25%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    }
#image-nav3{
    background:#FF0;
    width:25%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    }
#image-nav4{
    background:#999;
    width:25%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    }

#footer{
    width:100%;
    background:#F9F;
    }
```

**EDIT** - Adding overflow:hidden to the parent div makes it disapear and the footer has not be fixed to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

```
  #footer{
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          }
```

Try this to fix the bottom fixed.
Try to change id to footer element it is useful.Or use predefined clearfix to the footer div.

[jsfiddle.net/pgamj71f/5](http://jsfiddle.net/pgamj71f/5)

Comment: That makes the #image-nav div disappear?

Comment: are you using bootstrap?Can you add screenshot?

Comment: here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pgamj71f/, ill add a screenshot to the post now

Comment: Relative is changed to fixed

Comment: Thanks, however my I do not want the footer to be fixed, the footer has to be under the main content

Comment: this doesnt work, fixed content overlaps other content

Comment: @5kud Try changing to absolute

Comment: your js fiddle with the fixed bottom will result in the footer constantly displaying on screen and hiding content behin id it if it flows longer which is not what i was looking for.

overflow:hidden resulted in the content disappearing all together, but it stays present when a set width and height is added which fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

to fix this overlap the parent element must have a set width and height.

```
#image-nav{
height:18px;
}
```

must be added for overflow:hidden to work